# How can I count the red circles I drew?

Tags: image-processing, image

[image]

I reached there the last step is to count the circles. Please help me.

Comment: Please post the code as code and not as an image. You should also post the input to your code, `img2`, so that others can reproduce your result.

Answer (score 2):

`Length[comps]` will answer your question. If you only know the Graphics-object (`pict=Show[...]`) you can count as follows:

```
Length@Cases[pict, _Circle, Infinity]
```